# Problems with the last chrome update - CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

so, i'm an intern on my company, and need to deal with some stuff that i'm not 100%.
The thing is, the last google chrome update crashed some css in my java web app. We do work with a table, based on scrum. Basicly a taskboard, where you can set a task, remove it, set is as "to do, doing and done". But, since 12/12 +/- your task was missing from the taskboard. We didn't knew what was going on at the begining, but after a little research we found out that the style of the 'height:100%' of tr td was crashing, and making everything desapear. It works fine in firefox and also in IE. when we did remove the height, the tasks appeared. But the thing is, without the height:100% the jquery droppable ui, that we use to move the tasks inside the table was set to the height automatically, even when it is with height 100%. 
We don't want to set a minimal height, because it was supposed to work pretty fine.

Here is the code, it's a little big to text in here, so i typed it on jsfiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/rychardgoltara/bvw1hkxg/

```
    <tr data-bind="attr:{id: sequencial}" id="2093" class ="selectable">
    <td class ="historia" style="height:1px">
      <div class="colapsada" style="display:none;">
      </div>
      <div class="expandida">
        <div class="historiaLayout">
          <span id=""></span>
        </div>
      </div> 
     </td>
      <!-- ko foreach: {data: $root.fases, as : 'fase'} -->      
   <td data-bind="css : 'fase-' + id" class="fase-7">
     <div class="colapsada"></div>
     <div class="expandida tarefaExpandida">
       <div class="nomeFase fase">
                        <span class="tamanhoVariavel sh-tooltip" data-bind="text: titulo, attr: {'aria-label': titulo}" aria-label="A Fazer">A Fazer</span>
            }
    .tabelaQT tbody tr td {
    border-right: 1px #ccc solid;
    height: 100%;
}
.tarefaExpandida {
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
```

One of our solutions was setting the height:100% on tr td and also setting it to height:-webkit-calc(0px). So it can work fine on chrome without affecting other browsers. But the thing is, this solution is the real solution? Am i missing something? And if this is the solution, why is it? I don't know how to explain the solution to my boss. Here is a pic of what is looks like, and what should looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcdOm.jpg

Comment: Any way to create a fiddle with content? Thanks

Comment: with a content you mean, the whole code?

Comment: a minimum reproduceable example of the bug you believe you're encountering.

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce it without using the whole code. As i said i'm a student doing an internship in a company. Got here a couple weeks ago.

Comment: But i do guarantee you that the problem is in the part i've wrote on the fiddle.